# Back to the roots - connection Canoscan 4200F

Tags: system-installation, canon

Is there a Linux-SW which are able to go with a "Canoscan 4200F"?

My Computer is a HP-Laptop compaq nc6120 with 74GB hard disc (14GB used) 1,86GHz 32Bit and in the moment running on Windows XP-pro.
I tried already Ubuntu 15.04 (newest 32 Bit version I found) but it sticks always, takes a lot of time to create from DVD. This is not a solution.

Greetings

Rolf

Comment: Hello Rolf, welcome to askubuntu.15.04 is not a supported version. Better use 16.04, which is a Long Term Support version. A 32bit version can be found here http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.5/ . The Canonscan 4200F seems to be a terrible choice with regard to linux support.

Answer (score 0):

Canon does not supply Linux drivers for their devices.

Specific the "Canoscan 4200F" does not work with the [SANE backend](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON). Their site has some good info on thise device and lists [Chipsets](http://www.sane-project.org/unsupported/canon-4200f.html) used and the USB connection info. It is possible to [contact](http://www.sane-project.org/mailing-lists.html) the maintainers of the sane package. Maybe you can supply them with the needed information to get this printer added to their backend.

All in all I would advice to purchase a printer and scanner that does support Linux.